# How to pass function/callback to child process in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

Let's say I have a `parent.js` containing a method named `parent`

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');

var options = {
    someData: {a:1, b:2, c:3},
    asyncFn: function (data, callback) { /*do other async stuff here*/ }
};

function Parent(options, callback) {
    var child = childProcess.fork('./child');
    child.send({
        method: method,
        options: options
    });
    child.on('message', function(data){
        callback(data,err, data,result);
        child.kill();
    });
}
```

Meanwhile in `child.js`

```
process.on('message', function(data){
    var method = data.method;
    var options = data.options;
    var someData = options.someData;
    var asyncFn = options.asyncFn; // asyncFn is undefined at here
    asyncFn(someData, function(err, result){
        process.send({
            err: err,
            result: result
        });
    });
});
```

I was wondering if passing functions to child process is not allowed in Node.js.

Why would `asyncFn` become `undefined` after it is sent to the `child`?

Is it related to `JSON.stringify`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JSON doesn't support serializing functions (at least out of the box). You could convert the function to its string representation first (via `asyncFn.toString()`) and then re-create the function again in the child process. The problem though is you lose scope and context with this process, so your function really has to be standalone.

Complete example:

`parent.js`:

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');

var options = {
  someData: {a:1, b:2, c:3},
  asyncFn: function (data, callback) { /*do other async stuff here*/ }
};
options.asyncFn = options.asyncFn.toString();

function Parent(options, callback) {
  var child = childProcess.fork('./child');
  child.send({
    method: method,
    options: options
  });
  child.on('message', function(data){
    callback(data,err, data,result);
    child.kill();
  });
}
```

`child.js`:

```
process.on('message', function(data){
  var method = data.method;
  var options = data.options;
  var someData = options.someData;
  var asyncFn = new Function('return ' + options.asyncFn)();
  asyncFn(someData, function(err, result){
    process.send({
      err: err,
      result: result
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Aww, beat me to it :P

Comment: is `new Function('return ' + funcString)();` safe for untrusted code?

Comment: @M4GNV5 No, you'd need to instead use the `vm` module in a child process with the appropriate OS-level protections in place to be safe with "untrusted code."